# Check if the path input is URL or Local File

Tags: c#

I'm working in xmldataprovider and we have configuration value "source" this value may be local file or url 
like

> c:\data\test.xml --absolute
>   data\test.xml  --relative
>
> or url http:\mysite\test.xml

how I can determine all this cases in code
I'm working c#

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
private static bool IsLocalPath(string p)
{
  return new Uri(p).IsFile;
}
```

...or, if you want to include support for certain invalid URIs...

```
private static bool IsLocalPath(string p)
{
  if (p.StartsWith("http:\\"))
  {
    return false;
  }

  return new Uri(p).IsFile;
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  CheckIfIsLocalPath("C:\\foo.txt");
  CheckIfIsLocalPath("C:\\");
  CheckIfIsLocalPath("http://www.txt.com");
}

private static void CheckIfIsLocalPath(string p)
{
  var result = IsLocalPath(p); ;

  Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}  {2}", result, p, new Uri(p).AbsolutePath);
}
```

Comment: when I use this for relative, I got the following exception
 Run-time exception thrown : System.UriFormatException - Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: @ahmed: For the `http:\mysite\test.xml` one, right?  That one isn't a valid Uri.  You might have to add logic to the method to short-cut using, perhaps, a condition like `p.StartsWith(@"http:\")`.

Comment: oh yes sorry http:\ this is my mistake it is Http:\\

Answer (score 3):

Just using `new Uri(yourPath)` won't work in all cases.

Comparing various scenarios (via LinqPad).

```
    var tests = new[] {
        Path.GetTempFileName(),
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetTempFileName()),
        "http://in.ter.net",
        "http://in.ter.net/",
        "http://in.ter.net/subfolder/",
        "http://in.ter.net/subfolder/filenoext",
        "http://in.ter.net/subfolder/file.ext",
        "http://in.ter.net/subfolder/file.ext?somequerystring=yes",
        Path.GetFileName(Path.GetTempFileName()),
        Path.Combine("subfolder", Path.GetFileName(Path.GetTempFileName())),
    };

    tests.Select(test => {
        Uri u;
        try {
            u = new Uri(test);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            return new {
                test,
                IsAbsoluteUri = false,
                // just assume
                IsFile = true,
            };
        }

        return new {
            test,
            u.IsAbsoluteUri,
            u.IsFile,
        };
    }).Dump();
```

### Results

[image: Linqpad results of path checking]

Comment: This solution won't work for urls like www.google.com, which returns IsFile=true

Answer (score 3):

In case of a malformed path (non-existing path,empty string, null string) Uri(p).IsFile throws an exception.
In my opinion is better to use two methods to discern what is what:

```
private bool PathIsLocalFile(string path)
{
    return File.Exists(path);
}

private bool PathIsUrl(string path)
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
        return false;
    try
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(path);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

//

```
Microsoft docs: 
public static bool Exists(string path);
```

Returns:
true if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the name of an existing file; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if path is  null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.
//

```
Microsoft docs: 
public Uri(string uriString);
```

Exceptions:

```
T:System.ArgumentNullException:
```

uriString is null.

```
T:System.UriFormatException:
```

uriString is empty.-or- The scheme specified in uriString is not correctly formed.   See System.Uri.CheckSchemeName(System.String).-or- uriString contains too many   slashes.-or- The password specified in uriString is not valid.-or- The host name   specified in uriString is not valid.-or- The file name specified in uriString   is not valid. -or- The user name specified in uriString is not valid.-or- The   host or authority name specified in uriString cannot be terminated by backslashes.-or-   The port number specified in uriString is not valid or cannot be parsed.-or-   The length of uriString exceeds 65519 characters.-or- The length of the scheme   specified in uriString exceeds 1023 characters.-or- There is an invalid character   sequence in uriString.-or- The MS-DOS path specified in uriString must start   with c:\.

Answer (score 2):

This is a version of @drzaus 's answer avoiding exception handling approach. There is a [Uri.TryCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate) available.

```
        var tests = new[] {
        Path.GetTempFileName(),
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetTempFileName()),
        "http://in.ter.net",
        "http://in.ter.net/",
        "http://in.ter.net/subfolder/",
        "http://in.ter.net/subfolder/filenoext",
        "http://in.ter.net/subfolder/file.ext",
        "http://in.ter.net/subfolder/file.ext?somequerystring=yes",
        Path.GetFileName(Path.GetTempFileName()),
        Path.Combine("subfolder", Path.GetFileName(Path.GetTempFileName()))};

        tests.Select(test =>
        {
            if (Uri.TryCreate(test, UriKind.Absolute, out var u))
            {
                return new { test, u.IsAbsoluteUri, u.IsFile };
            }

            return new { test, IsAbsoluteUri = false, IsFile = true };
        }

        ).Dump();
```

And as extension methods:

```cs
        public static bool IsLocalAbsolutePath(this string input)
        {
            if (Uri.TryCreate(input, UriKind.Absolute, out var uri))
            {
                return uri.IsFile;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static bool IsRemoteAbsolutePath(this string input)
        {
            if (Uri.TryCreate(input, UriKind.Absolute, out var uri))
            {
                return !uri.IsFile;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the rule for all remote file, it should (and it must) include the protocol in the URI:

```
http://
ftp://
```

and for local file, it can be

```
file://
```

for absolute path and no protocol for relative.

Then simple regex could help extracting the right information.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who would like to always get an absolute Uri:

```cs
bool TryGetAbsoluteUri(string? path, out Uri? uri)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
    {
        uri = null;
        return false;
    }
    if (Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
        return true;

    return Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Relative, out uri) &&
           Uri.TryCreate(new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), UriKind.Absolute), uri, out uri);
}
```

This works with the above test cases, but converts any relative file's to their absolute Uri based on the current working directory.

**Note** what it *doesn't* do is check for invalid file characters, which is something you could add relatively easily using `Path`.