# User Permissions issue

Tags: c#, xml, url, permissions, directory

I am using Visual Studio C# to parse an XML document for a file location from a local search tool I am using. Specifically I am using c# to query if the user has access to certain files and hide those to which it does not have access. I seem to have files that should return access is true however because not all files are local (IE some are web files without proper names) it is not showing access to files it should be showing access to. The error right now is caused by a url using `.aspx?i=573`, is there a work around or am I going to have to just remove all of these files... =/

Edit: More info...

I am using right now....

```
foreach (XmlNode xn in nodeList)
            {

                string url = xn.InnerText;
                //Label1.Text = url;
                try
                { using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(url)) {  }
                }
                catch { i++; Label2.Text = i.ToString(); Label1.Text = url; }


            }
```

The issue is, when it attempts to open files like the ...`.aspx?i=573` it puts them in the catch stack. If I attempt to open the file however the file opens just fine. (IE I have read access but because of either the file type or the append of the '?=' in the file name it tosses it into the unreadable stack.

I want everything that is readable either via url or local access to display else it will catch the error files for me.

Comment: It would be helpful for the readers too if you specify what kind of error you're getting and some code snippets would be invaluable too.

Comment: It is not so much an error per-say in that it is working almost as intended the issue is it is filtering out objects that I have access to. Ill add more information though thank you.

Comment: also avoid using the try catch blocks to control the flow of the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileStream reads and writes local files. "?" is not valid character for local file name.

It looks like you want to open local  and remote files. If it is what you are trying to do you should use approapriate metod of downloading for each type - i.e. for HTTP you WebRequest or related classes.

Note: it would be much easier to answer if you'd say: when url is "..." `File.OpenRead(url)` failes with exception, mesasge "...".

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but if you only want the path of a URI, you can easily drop the query string portion like this:

```
        Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.domain.com/");
        Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "home/default.aspx?i=573");

        Console.WriteLine(myUri.AbsolutePath); // ie "home/default.aspx"
```

You cannot have ? in file names in Windows, but they are valid in URIs (that is why IE can open it, but Windows cannot).

Alternatively, you could just replace the '?' with some other character if you are converting a URL to a filename.

In fact thinking about it now, you could just check to see if your "document" was a URI or not, and if it isn't then try to open the file on the file system. Sounds like you are trying to open any and everything that is supplied, but it wouldn't hurt to performs some checks on the data.

```
private static bool IsLocalPath(string p)
{
  return new Uri(p).IsFile;
}
```

This is from [Check if the path input is URL or Local File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528415/check-if-the-path-input-is-url-or-local-file) it looks like exactly what you are looking for.