# Getting the url of the current request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page for registering students and an email activation link is sent after submitting records. I have included the link for activation but it gets the whole url and includes it in the email. Can someone show how to solve the issue as currently it sends the whole page url in the email? Here is a sample of what is send to email:

> localhost:89192/Staff/Register.aspx?rwndrnd=0.6363636646446373333CompleteRegistration.aspx?id=8901b88k1-81fa-8u10-m96e-892f6aea6710

Below is how am getting the current url

```
activationUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host+""+"://CompleteAccount.aspx?id=" + id.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use

```
activationUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

Also, `Request.Url.ToString()` returns the full url (including querystring)

Comment: This gets for me the whole url currently in the page registration but i needed to include the url+the activation page by getting only the url+ the activation link this format ..                   `localhost:89192/CompleteRegistration.aspx?id=8901b88k1-81fa-8u10-m96e-892f6aea6710`

Comment: What is your current `url` and what is your expected result?

Comment: Below is  my current url showing when i use activationUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri     `http://localhost:89192/Staff/Register.aspx?rwndrnd=0.6363636646446373333`    my expexted result is to include my Activation Page which is `CompleteRegistration.aspx?id=8901b88k1-81fa-8u10-m96e-892f6aea6710` when sending the email link.The url changes at times since have published it.I was hard coding but i now need it to include the current url+the activation page link

Comment: Unclear with your comment, if you want to change url try `Response.Redirect("~/CompleteRegistration.aspx?id=8901b88k1-81fa-8u10-m96e-892f6aea6710");`

Comment: This is what i mean,i have a page called Activate Account and another page called Register.When one registers,an email is send to him which contains the url with link to Activate Account.My application runs locally in my machine and have also published it whereby i have also the link for that.I needed it to act in a way such that if i am running it on  the remote server,it picks that url   too.I had coded it but i  need always to pick the curreny url whether locall  url address or the remote url.I hope this gives light to you now

Comment: Do you want to check whether the current url is local or remote?

Comment: Yes really.thats what i need  to

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528415/check-if-the-path-input-is-url-or-local-file

Comment: several questions are already asked. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354477/method-to-determine-if-path-string-is-local-or-remote-machine

Comment: @Jopito have you got it?

Comment: my server has gone down and i cannot confirm whether its solved  so as i can test the remote URL,however.this is what i have used in my code and seems to be what i was looking at.Below is the snippet of code i have used  `activationUrl = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);`
                                `newUrl = activationUrl + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/ActivateAccount.aspx?id=" + id.ToString() + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(newUrl));`