# WebClient must not serve local files

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I have a simple reverse proxy to avoid CORS in the browser. 
In essence, it works like this:

```
string url = Request.QueryString["url"];
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    byte[] buffer = webClient.DownloadData(url);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
}
```

Usage:

```
/reverseproxy.aspx?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F
```

However, this has a vulnerability. The following request will return the logs of my IIS server.

```
/reverseproxy.aspx?url=c%3A%2Finetpub%2Flogs%2FLogFiles%2FW3SVC1%2Fu_ex170712.log
```

Is there a way to tell WebClient to **not serve local files**?
Without setting permissions and without using `File.Exists(url)`

Comment: One crazy requirement is, is that the local files must stay local...

Comment: There are plenty of other ways in which this seems like a bad idea. Can you not apply some form of *whitelist* for URLs that (you believe) are safe for you to proxy in this manner?

Comment: A whitelist would indeed be safer. However, our server will be installed for many customers with all different external servers they will refer to. I'll consider it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if your provided URI is an URL or a file reference using the [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You could use the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2528443/993547):

```
private static bool IsLocalPath(string p)
{
  return new Uri(p).IsFile;
}
```

Even safer would be to check the `scheme` of the `Uri` to match to `http` or `https`:

```
private static bool IsHttpOrHttps(string uri)
{
    Uri u = new Uri(uri);
    return u.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || u.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
}
```

Comment: new Uri(p).IsFile is nice because it will also throw an exception on other mad inputs. However, isn't it possible to configure WebClient to avoid local files?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You can try `HttpWebRequest` instead.

Comment: @PatrickHofman you can reconfigure the protocol factory in the web.config. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extra assembly that creates your own implementation for a `WebRequest` and then [configure your web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/add-element-for-webrequestmodules-network-settings) to use your custom implementation for the file protocol.

Here is what you need:

#### Factory

This class decides if the reqest uri is local or not, add your own checks if needed.

```
public class NoLocalFile: IWebRequestCreate
{
    public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
    {
            // add your own extra checks here
            // for example what Patrick offered in his answer
            // I didn't test if I can't create a local UNC path
            if (uri.IsFile && !uri.IsUnc)
            {
                // this is a local file request, we're going to return something safe by 
                // creating our own custom WebRequest
                return (WebRequest) new NoLocalFileRequest(); 
            }
            else
            {
                // this should allow non local file request
                // if needed
                return FileWebRequest.Create(uri);
            }
    }
}
```

#### NoLocalFileRequest

This is the minimal implementation needed for our custom WebRequest

```
public class NoLocalFileRequest:WebRequest
{
    // return an instance of our custom webResponse
    public override WebResponse GetResponse()
    {
        return new NoLocalFileResponse();
    }
}
```

#### NoLocalFileResponse

This class implements a WebResponse and returns a memorystream with the ASCII representation of the string "NO!". Here it is required to implement the ContentLength property as well.

```
public class NoLocalFileResponse : WebResponse {

    static byte[] responseBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("NO!");

    public override long ContentLength
    {
        get {
            return responseBytes.Length;
        }
        set {              
            // whatever
        }
    }

    public override Stream GetResponseStream()
    {
        // what you want to return goes here
        return new MemoryStream(responseBytes);
    }
}
```

If you put these classes in a namespace called `MyCustomWebRequests` and compile this to an assembly called BlockLocalFile.dll, copy that assembly in the bin folder of your webapplication, then all you need is to make or add these changes to your web.config:

```xml
<system.net>
  <webRequestModules>
    <remove prefix="file:"/>
    <add prefix="file:" type="MyCustomWebRequests.NoLocalFile, BlockLocalFile"/>
  </webRequestModules>
</system.net>
```

When you testdrive this you should find that your previous code still works unchanged while the browsers that try the local file trick will get "NO!" returned instead of your file content.

Be aware that this config change applies to all code that runs in the appdomain of that webapplication. If you have legit code that also does require the normal use of the file protocol you have to make changes to the factory method that decides which WebRequest to create.